# Unzip for Triple in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin, if I have a pair I can get a list of first values and second values like this:

```
val(firstList, secondList) = listOfPairs.unzip()
// listOfPairs: List<Pair<String, Long>>
```

How can I do the same for a `Triple`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How bout something like this:

```
fun <X>List<Triple<X,X,X>>.unzip(): List<List<X>> {
    return fold(listOf(ArrayList<X>(), ArrayList<X>(), ArrayList<X>())){ r, i ->
        r[0].add(i.first)
        r[1].add(i.second)
        r[2].add(i.third)
        r
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val triplesList = listOf(Triple(1,"s",3), Triple(1,"u",3), Triple(1,"p",3))
val (listOne, listTwo, listThree) = triplesList.unzip()

println("ListOne: $listOne")
println("ListTwo: $listTwo")
println("ListThree: $listThree")

/* Output:
    ListOne: [1, 1, 1]
    ListTwo: [s, u, p]
    ListThree: [3, 3, 3]
 */
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBPS8QwEMXPyacYiocEssXV21IL3he87GFBPBSbsoMxLZN0RZd@9po/LcoKEgiT30vezMtb7w3aee5GC9Wx3qPz1YFwMLo6qrDquhztFw5C7iCJaQsYLpyR9iNZ6HrTChP4UyceiZrP5Y6QCv4/S3kBUoCwqTlj9Hz7UjZtK7DskJyXiW1X5vRrb9sM71boT0iZcTbxifMY5L1BK2Sc8NwY8CmOi03hAZY5c0axVYUr1H0Y7AeM12CIQGaznNNqlYwOH/1SnEhrGex/NVs/jnM2EFpvrCj2@fUObhafQl6pwXJRQ/VXjX1WPdbhxjTP3w)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
val firstList = listOf(triple1, triple2).map {it.first }

val secondList = listOf(triple1, triple2).map { it.second }

val thirdList = listOf(triple1, triple2).map { it.third }
```

or

```
val result = listOf(triple1, triple2).map {
    Triple(it.first, it.second, it.third)    
}
```